# CFIMAP and Embedded Attachment Download

Tags: email, coldfusion, attachment

I have a ColdFusion 9 application I inherited that signs into an Outlook email box then processes email, downloads attachments, and saves emails sent to it into a database for long term storage. This solution is working fine via cfimap until it gets an email where there are attachments embedded into the message body.

**The basic process for an email with attachments is as follows:**

1. Check for and save new email to database
2. Check for and save listed attachments to storage filer
3. If it has attachments, check to make sure attachments were downloaded.
4. If has attachments and attachments were downloaded, mark email for delete.
5. Email deleted from inbox.

The problem I am encountering is in emails where the attachments are embedded into the body of the message.

**For example, when I output**

SUBJECT: My Email with Embedded Images and Documents

ATTACHMENTS: image001.gif image002.gif image003.gif image004.gif image005.gif image006.gif image007.gif 1200084.DOC.DOC

ATTACHMENTFILES:

As you can see it says there are ATTACHMENTS, but when you check the ATTACHMENTFILES, there is nothing. When I sign into outlook, I can see the word document listed as an attachment as well as the embedded images inside the message body.

So my goal is to write a cleanup script that will finish downloading the attachments on these emails so that we can save them into long term storage and then delete the email from outlook. Does anyone have a solution to download attachments that are embedded into the body of an email message and do not appear in the ATTACHMENTFILES list?

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing an Exchange Server, you might want to try using the CFEXCHANGE tag.  It seems to be more capable and reliable than the CFIMAP tag.  I've been battling the same problem with CFIMAP for more than a year.  Since there doesn't appear to be a way to access the object created by the CFIMAP "getAll" command before the files are enumerated, there is no way to do any clean up.