# How to break the list of attachments from CFIMAP for simple display only

Tags: coldfusion

I am using CFIMAP to retrieve e-mail and display the information on a web-page.  I don't want to download the attachments(yet).  All I want to do is display the list of attachments as a bulleted list.  When I retrieve the e-mail using action="GETALL", the attachments field returns a list of filenames, but I am not able to determine how the list is delimited, so I do not know where one file ends and the next one begins.  How do I break the list of attachments from CFIMAP for simple display?

Comment: What does the list of filenames look like?  `cfdump` the CFIMAP return variable and post the results here.

Comment: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt

Comment: Like I said, there are no delimiters, no way to separate them.  I couldn't possibly separate on all possible extensions.  And some filenames have spaces so I couldn't use those either.

Comment: Yes but are spaces sent as such or are they sent encoded like `%20`? It has to be delimited somehow even for ColdFusion to handle it internally.

Comment: When I use "Inspect Element", it doesn't show any encoding.  When I copy and paste into Notepad++ and view the symbols, it doesn't show any encoding or custom symbols separating them.

Comment: Actually...I just noticed that I think they may be tab-delimited!

Comment: Hopefully they are. Seems like they must be delimited by something you can use. Otherwise this seems to be an issue for a while - [CFIMAP and Embedded Attachment Download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23701171/1636917)

Comment: It worked.  They are definitely tab-delimited, and arraytolist(attachments,chr(9)) worked perfectly.  Not sure how I should give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Yep, I found this ColdFusion bug that was entered mentioning it is tab delimited - https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3847740. Glad you figured it out. Go ahead and post an answer so others can find this in the future. It is okay to answer your own question and accept it as the answer. I just troubleshooted with you.

Answer (score 2):

The attachment list is tab-delimited, and arraytolist(attachments,chr(9)) worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

A google search on `cfimap` led me [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfimap.html).  It describes an attribute called `attachmentpath`, which specifies the folder where the attachments are held.

Armed with that information I would create a directory with a unique name and use that name in the `attachmentpath` attribute.  Then I would use the `cfdirectory` tag to create a query object listing the attached files, and loop through the records to create my bullet list.

At some point I would have to delete these directories and attachments.  I would do that with a scheduled job.

Comment: That would require them to be downloaded, which I don't want to do yet. I read all the same things.